# sortable - connectWith doesn't work - lorem ipsum

Tags: jquery-ui

```js
$('.wrapca, .wrapcb').sortable({
  containment: "parent",
  connectWith: ".wrapca, .wrapcb",
  axis: "x",
  tolerance: "pointer"
});
```

```css
.wrapca, .wrapcb{
 width:30%;
 display:inline-grid;
 grid-template-columns:repeat(2, 1fr);
 grid-gap:5px;
}

.inside{
cursor:cell;
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div style="text-align:justify; text-align-last:justify;">
<div class='wrap wrapca'>
<div class='inside'>lorem</div>
<div class='inside'>ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class='wrap wrapcb'>
<div class='inside'>lorem</div>
<div class='inside'>ipsum</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Why `connectWith` doesn't work here?

Answer (score 0):

> A selector of other sortable elements that the items from this list should be connected to. This is a one-way relationship, if you want the items to be connected in both directions, the `connectWith` option must be set on both sortable elements.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.wrap').sortable({
    containment: $(".wrap").parent(),
    connectWith: ".wrap",
    //axis: "x",
    tolerance: "pointer"
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapca,
.wrapcb {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.inside {
  cursor: cell;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div style="text-align:justify; text-align-last:justify;">
  <div class='wrap wrapca'>
    <div class='inside'>lorem</div>
    <div class='inside'>ipsum</div>
  </div>

  <div class='wrap wrapcb'>
    <div class='inside'>lorem</div>
    <div class='inside'>ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I suspect you were being too aggressive in your code. Also, the containment was too strict.

Comment: your snippet doen't work properly. left and right pair are not sortable by itself

Comment: @puerto I can sort them in their list and I can move them from list to list. I am not able to replicate not being able to sort within itself.

Comment: @puerto is is a little difficult to do. This is related to the amount of spacing available to identify `over` in each list. I would consider adding some padding, but they do work as expected.

Comment: left `lorem` cannot be placed after left ` ipsum` and vice versa. And the same for the right pair.